# update_recordset on tempDB table in ssrs report in d365

Tags: report, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

I have to do an update for some fields after insert in a `tempDB table` inside a `report`.

I wrote this snippet:

```
private void updateField()
{
   update_recordset GlobalTempDBVariable
   setting field3 = GlobalTempDBVariable.field1 + GlobalTempDBVariable.field2;
}
```

But when i open the report i don't see this value updated. any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you debugged the issue yet?

If you extend SrsReportDataProviderPreProcess in your DP class instead of SRSReportDataProviderBase you can debug your DP class and see if the table is even being filled up correctly.

If that doesn't clear anything up, try looping through the temp table at that point to see if there is even any data in there to update.